# Finding overlaps between multiple nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, I have one large dictionary which contains smaller nested dictionaries.

The dictionary could have as many as 7 nested dictionaries, and up to 100 'exons'. There will always be overlaps between some of exons. Here is a relatively small example:

```
{
    0: {
        "exon_count": 4,
        "length": 29832,
        "exon": {
            0: {"start": 77, "end": 323},
            1: {"start": 1245, "end": 1507},
            2: {"start": 6225, "end": 6598},
            3: {"start": 29186, "end": 29909},
        },
    },
    1: {
        "exon_count": 3,
        "length": 6688,
        "exon": {
            0: {"start": 0, "end": 323},
            1: {"start": 1245, "end": 1507},
            2: {"start": 6225, "end": 6688},
        },
    },
    2: {
        "exon_count": 4,
        "length": 6688,
        "exon": {
            0: {"start": 0, "end": 323},
            1: {"start": 487, "end": 971},
            2: {"start": 1245, "end": 1507},
            3: {"start": 6225, "end": 6688},
        },
    },
}
```

I am struggling to find a way to extract all of the overlaps between the exons. I.e. only extracting start and end coordinates which appear in *every* nested dictionary.

Here are the overlaps in this example:

```
77-323
1245-1507
6225-6598
```

I thought of using a basic for loop, but I don't think it works well here. Please help!

Comment: Shouldn't the last output line be `6225-6598` due to the first exon?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `0-323`!

Comment: @Thomas Yes you are right, I've now corrected it. Apologies for the mistake!

Comment: @SM1312 It cannot start from 0 because the first exon only starts from 77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all integers in these ranges into a `set`, then intersect all the `set`s, and finally convert the resulting `set` back into a list of ranges. It's not the most efficient in theory, because it depends on the size of the ranges (`end - start`). But if those are always in the same ballpark as your example, it shouldn't matter.

Here's an implementation with some explanatory comments and doctests.

```
def overlaps(exons_dict):
    '''
    Computes overlap between all exons in the dictionary. Returns it as a list
    of (start, end) tuples, with start and end inclusive.

    >>> overlaps(EXAMPLE)
    [(77, 323), (1245, 1507), (6225, 6598)]
    '''
    # Handle the case of no exons, otherwise there is no first.
    if not exons_dict:
        return []
    # Create an iterator over all exons.
    exons = iter(exons_dict.values())
    # Initialize the overlap set from the first exon.
    overlap = exon_values(next(exons))
    # Intersect current overlap with each successive exon.
    for exon in exons:
        overlap.intersection_update(exon_values(exon))
    # Turn the overlap set back into a list of ranges.
    return values_to_ranges(overlap)

def exon_values(exon):
    '''
    Given an exon, converts all values in all its ranges into a set.
    '''
    values = set()
    for row in exon["exon"].values():
        for i in range(row["start"], row["end"] + 1):
            values.add(i)
    return values

def values_to_ranges(values):
    '''
    Turns a set into a list of (start, end) tuples, with start and end
    inclusive.

    >>> values_to_ranges({7, 6, 1, 8, 3, 2})
    [(1, 3), (6, 8)]
    >>> values_to_ranges({4, 3})
    [(3, 4)]
    >>> values_to_ranges(set())
    []
    '''
    # Sort the values into an ascending list.
    sorted_values = sorted(list(values))
    # Extract ranges.
    ranges = []
    for value in sorted_values:
        # Does current value belong to latest range?
        if ranges and value == ranges[-1][1] + 1:
            # Yes: extend current range.
            ranges[-1] = (ranges[-1][0], value)
        else:
            # No: create a new range.
            ranges.append((value, value))
    return ranges
```

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion to travel in the dictionary until the `exon` key is met, then append all "intervals" as pairs. The overlaps are found by computing the intersection of each possible pairing (the `set -> range -> interval` approach is taken from Thomas otherwise do a `if-else` hunt to find the min and max).

```
import itertools as it

data = # from question

def exon_overlaps(data: dict):
    overlaps = []

    for k in data:
        if isinstance(next_d := data[k], dict):
            if k != 'exon':
                overlaps.extend(exon_overlaps(next_d))
            else:
                overlaps.extend((interval['start'], interval['end']) for interval in next_d.values())
                return overlaps
    return overlaps


intervals = exon_overlaps(d)

# step 2: find intersections
overlaps = []
for (a, b), (c, d) in it.combinations(intervals, 2):
    if (a, b) != (c, d):
        if (i := set.intersection(set(range(a, b+1)), set(range(c, d+1)))) != set():
            if (interval := f'{min(i)}-{max(i)}') not in overlaps:
                overlaps.append(interval)

print(overlaps)
```

Output

```
['77-323', '6225-6598']
```

*Remark*: The output is different from the one in the question because is not explained how repeated interval should be treated in a consistent way