# How to remove overlapping item in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I am trying to delete the overlapping values in a nested list.

The data looks like this:

```
[[22, 37, 'foobar'], [301, 306, 'foobar'],[369, 374, 'foobar'], [650, 672, 'foobar'], [1166, 1174, 'foobar'],[1469, 1477, 'foobar'],[2237, 2245, 'foobar'],[2702, 2724, 'foobar'],[3426, 3446, 'foobar'],[3505, 3513, 'foobar'],[3756, 3764, 'foobar'],[69524, 69535, 'foobar'],[3812, 3820, 'foobar'],[4034, 4057, 'foobar'],[4318, 4347, 'foobar'],[58531, 58548, 'foobar'],[4552, 4574, 'foobar'],[4854, 4861, 'foobar'],[5769, 5831, 'foobar'], [5976, 5986, 'foobar'],[6541, 6558, 'foobar'],[6541, 6608, 'foobar'],[7351, 7364, 'foobar'],[7351, 7364, 'foobar'], [7764, 7770, 'foobar'],[58540, 58548, 'foobar'],[69524, 69556, 'foobar']]
```

There are some overlapping values in index 0 and 1 of across the list. Such as:

```
 [6541, 6558, 'foobar'] overlaps with [6541, 6608, 'foobar']
 [7351, 7364, 'foobar'] overlaps with [7351, 7364, 'foobar']
 [58531, 58548, 'foobar'] overlaps with [58540, 58548, 'foobar']
 [69524, 69535, 'foobar'] overlaps with [69524, 69556, 'foobar']
```

I am trying to go through the list and remove shorter first instance of the overlapping values. If
`[6541, 6558, 'foobar']` overlaps with `[6541, 6608, 'foobar']` I want to keep `[6541, 6608, 'foobar']` and remove `[6541, 6558, 'foobar']` from the list.

So far i tried:

```
def clean_span(adata):
    data = adata.copy()
    rem_idx = []
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        if data[i][0] in data[i+1] or data[i][1] in data[i+1]:
            print(" {} overlaps with {}".format(data[i], data[i+1]))
            rem_idx.append(i)
    
    for i in rem_idx:
        del data[i]
    return data
```

But this code always leaves some overlapping values behind.

It is same with this approach as well.

```
def clean_span(adata):
    data = adata.copy()
    new_data = []
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        if data[i][0] in data[i+1] or data[i][1] in data[i+1]:
            print(" {} overlaps with {}".format(data[i], data[i+1]))
            new_data.append(data[i+1])
        else:
            new_data.append(data[i])
    return new_data
```

I would appreciate your help to solve this problem.

Comment: Interesting problem!

Comment: Check this - https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/solution/

Comment: similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778016/finding-overlaps-between-multiple-nested-dictionaries/71779224#71779224)

Comment: What if two overlapping ranges have the same span? What if multiple overlapping ranges exist like `1->5`, `4->10`, `8->12`, etc? Is the `'foobar'` in the lists relevant to the problem?

Comment: Great point! @PranavHosangadi  In this particular case, the spans are index offset of NER annotations. Problem we faced is that colleagues annotated some words, ie. [1,3,'foobar'], and later decided to annotate a bigger section i.e. [1,6,'foobar']. Problem we are trying to solve is to remove the first bits so the corpus is ready for training. Your questions are extremely relevant, and I just wish that problem does not come up at the moment :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def clean_span(adata):
  # to perform O(1) search for index 0 and 1
  # you can just have one dictionary if indexes don't matter
  d0 = dict()
  d1 = dict()

  r = []
  for a in adata:
    if a[0] in d0:
      print(str(a) + " overlaps with " + str(d0[a[0]]))
    elif a[1] in d1:
      print(str(a) + " overlaps with " + str(d1[a[1]]))
    else:  
      r.append(a)
      d0[a[0]] = a
      d1[a[1]] = a

  return r
```

Keep 2 dictionaries: one for first element and one for second. Then while iterating on the data, check if any of the keys exist in the respective dictionaries -- if the key is found, it is an overlap; else it is not.

---

Problem in your code:

```
if data[i][0] in data[i+1] or data[i][1] in data[i+1]:
    print(" {} overlaps with {}".format(data[i], data[i+1]))
    new_data.append(data[i+1])
else:
    new_data.append(data[i])
```

In the if statement, you add `i + 1` to the `new_data`. So naturally when the loop increments to `i + 1`, it goes into the `else` and it adds the overlapped element back to the list.

---

Side note:

```
if data[i][0] in data[i+1] or data[i][1] in data[i+1]:
```

You are trying to search the element in the entire list here. Making your time complexity `O(nk)`.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping can be found with `set.intersection`.

```
import itertools as it

l = # list

# merge the first two entries of the sublist into a from-to set values
m = ((set(range(p[0], p[1]+1)), p[2]) for p in l)

# combine each element of the list to check overlapping
new_l = []
for p1, p2 in it.combinations(m, 2):
    s1, l1 = p1
    s2, l2 = p2

    if set.intersection(s1, s2):
        m1, M1 = min(s1), max(s1)
        m2, M2 = min(s2), max(s2)

        # choose the biggest one
        if M2-m2 > M1-m1:
            new_l.append((m2, M2, l2))
        else:
            new_l.append((m1, M1, l1))

print(sorted(new_l, key=lambda p: p[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I convert your list to dict type. The keys are foobar1,foobar2,... then first items in nested list are value of new dict. The second loop and in result variable has duplicated values in
> rev_dict.The third loop find matches item then remove item from your list.

```
l_ist = [[22, 37, 'foobar'], ....]
ini_dict = {}
rev_dict = {}
for i in range(len(lis)):
   ini_dict[l_ist[i][2]+str(i)] = l_ist[i][0] 
for key, value in ini_dict.items():
   rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

result = [key for key, values in rev_dict.items()if len(values) > 1] # duplicated     values in rev_dic

for i in result:
    for j in range(len(lis)) :
        if i == l_ist[j][0]:
            l_ist[j].remove(i)
print(l_ist)
```